# Clang using anaconda installation instead of using default in MacOS

Tags: c, macos, clang

I am very new to using C on MacOS. I have been trying to compile C code on MacOS using clang, using the `make` command.

However, I want to use the default clang that comes with MacOS. When I type `which clang` on my Mac, it gives the result,

`/Users/prateek/opt/anaconda3/bin/clang`

instead of the standard clang that comes with MacOS, `/usr/bin/clang`.

Any ideas on how to change this back to the `/usr/bin/clang` ?

I am new to asking questions on StackOverflow as well, so please excuse my mistakes, if I have made any. Help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a line in your .bash_profile after the block added by conda installation.

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

Then it uses the clang in /usr/bin as you want. But I would recommend you use CommandLineTools clang instead because, otherwise, it can give you SDK version conflicts sometimes. You can just replace that with:

```
export PATH="/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin:$PATH"
```